# changing a tag class with PHP code

Tags: php, syntax, conditional-statements

lets say i have a tr

```
<tr class='condition1'> mysql db record </tr>
```

and if that record id shows also in other table i want it to color the tr

my logic goes like that:

> if record id is in the other table
>       change class to condition 2 and the css will put the color on in.

hope i made myself clear and understood. 
im just not quite sure about my php tools i can achieve that.

cheers.

Comment: You should probably get this info in the query.  Show us the query youre using and the table structures.

Answer (score 0):

Store all IDs in an array for example,

```
$ids = array();
```

And then on every loop (I'm assuming)

```
// If exists, add .color
    <tr class='condition1 <?php echo (isset($ids[$id]) ? 'color' : ''); ?>'> mysql db record </tr>

// Add to array
    $ids[$id] = TRUE;
```